# Is it wrong to add the same answer that another user posts at the same time?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

Just few minutes ago I have answered this question [Android runtime permission passes even if it doesn't have permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50943505/android-runtime-permission-passes-even-if-it-doesnt-have-permission/50943577?noredirect=1#comment88885164_50943577)

At the same time another user has also given the same answer.
The time difference between the two answer is just one minute.

Than the other user left a comment in my post like

> you post same answer @Sagar just add some posts why?
>
> yes but almost same its not any effect

Both answer are not same you can check the edit history.

So my question is

1. Did I make any mistake by answering that question?
2. What if two user give the same answer at the same time. In this situation can we say that one user has copy the answer of the other user?
3. Is this against the site rules?
4. Is my reply to that user is correct or not?

I replied to that user

> @AD10 we both have given ans at the same time just one min difference so you can not say that same

Comment: I do not know about this specific case (haven't followed the link), but if I answered one minute after someone else, and my answer was very similar to the other answer, I'd either edit my answer with more details and clarification to make it distinct enough, or I'd delete it if I though I couldn't bring anything else. But that's just my opinion. If by sheer luck two users answer the same thing at the same time, no one plagiarized anyone.

Comment: In my opinion, it's bad form to leave your answer if it doesn't contribute anything to existing answers, even if those existing answers appeared seconds before yours did. Future readers will expect answers to contain different content, and letting them read essentially the same answer twice is just wasting their time. It's not plagiarism or prohibited, though, just bad form and not very useful.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Actually, when I Google a question and find one on SO with two answers that are essentially the same, it gives me more confidence that the answer is right.

Comment: I think if both sides are obviously good-standing (which is visible from the posting times), then both should remain and the community will decide.